# Transformation of RV's Moments

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, random-variables, moment-generating-functions

Given a transformation of the RV $X$, how do it's moments transform?

**More Detailed Formulation**

Suppose that $X:(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, is a random variable *whose MGF exists* (ie: all its moments exist), and $f$ is a smooth function from $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.  Denote by $\mu^{i}\triangleq \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}\left[(X)^i\right]$.  Is there an expression for the $i^{th}$moment of $f(X)$ in terms of $\mu^1,\dots,\mu^i$?

Comment: Not really: take $f$ to be $\exp$. Then you need quite a few more moments of $X$. (Of course, if $f$ is itself a polynomial, then you can have an expression involving finitely many moments of $X$, but it will go beyond the $i$-th.)

Comment: Oh ya?  Is there a know for for this?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: A know formula (sorry typo)